# How do I move forward after a misunderstanding at our year end function?

Tags: communication, colleagues, conflict, south-africa

Last night we had our year end function at a local restaurant where a couple of tables were arranged to form one big square table.  At one stage a colleague who was sitting next to me moved a few chairs away to make space for someone else to be seated between us. At this point I jokingly asked why he is moving and if it is because I smell funny he must please tell me so I can do something about it.

He took great offence to this and insists many other people did too. Today I tried to apologize to him when he confronted me about "the way I treated him". He refuses to accept my apology and straight up told me that I now have an enemy in him.

Do I just leave things be or do I mail everyone who attended the function to apologize if my joke offended them?

Comment: Are you sure he isn't just joking around as well?

Comment: He made it very clear that he was serious

Comment: @SethR I concur. The part that made it sound like a joke is where he said you and him are enemies. That sounds rather silly and I probably would have laughed.

Comment: Just to be sure. could you put a country tag on this?  Cultural context might be important.

Comment: Do you suppose he thought you said that *he* smelled funny?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Do I just leave things be or do I mail everyone who attended the
>   function to apologize if my joke offended them?

This situation as described is so *trivial*, I would not give it a second thought.  Some folks like to hold on to silly grudges, and there isn't anything you can do about it.

**Short answer**:  You offended, *without intent*, and apologized for it in very short order.  At this point, move on and put this out of your mind.

Comment: It really is trivial. I will say, while I agree with this answer, different cultures have different points of view. So I can't gauge how "not serious" this is. Not to imply that it's VERY serious, but different cultures have different guidelines when it comes to simple things like this and a small thing can absolutely be a big thing long term. So, assuming the culture is similar to my own (Westerner), I think it's trivial.

Comment: @ShinEmperor Culture *could* play a role, but in a situation that literally is this trivial, I highly doubt it.  No location tag on the question, so not sure if I can add a culture angle to this answer -- or if it's worth the time.